# Как правильно ставить ударение в фамилии Мозголов?

Tags: ономастика, орфоэпия, фамилии

Как правильно ставить ударение в фамилии Мозголов?

Answer (score 5):

Спросите у Мозголова. 
Фамилии произносятся так, как считает правильным носитель.

Answer (score 0):

Можно **предположить**, что ударение падает на последний слог, исходя из истории этой фамилии. [Происхождение фамилии Мозголов | ufolog.ru](http://www.ufolog.ru/names/order/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2)

По одной из версий, фамилия Мозголов восходит к слову «мозголовый» - «человек весьма умный» или «мозголовить» - «долго думать; рассуждать».

Согласно другой гипотезе, фамилия Мозголов получилась в результате нескольких трансформаций: Мозгалёв — Мозголёв — Мозголов. В таком случае в основе этой фамилии лежит прозвище Мозгаль, которое также часто давалось умному человеку. Также не исключено, что это прозвище относится к так называемым «профессиональным» именованиям, содержащим указание на род деятельности человека. Возможно, человек по прозвищу Мозгаль занимал выборную должность. В старину мозгалями в шутку называли думных людей, советников, заседателей, гласных.

```
 **Дополнение но тему "Позволяется рассуждать о постановке ударения в фамилиях"**
```

**Вопросы и ответы на сайте Грамота.Ру**
 Как правильно ставить ударение в русских фамилиях на –ов, -ова (Иванов, Соколова)?   [СЛОВ ДРАГОЦЕННЫЕ КЛАДЫ | tmr-mo-rl.narod.ru](http://tmr-mo-rl.narod.ru/p14aa1.html)

**При подвижности и разноместности русского ударения вопрос о том, как следует произносить фамилии на - ов, является не праздным.** Исторически ударение в фамилии теснее всего связано с ударением в форме родительного падежа исходного существительного: если ударение подвижно в единственном числе, то оно в фамилии  переходит на суффикс: Пётр – Петра -   Петров; столяр – столяра – Столяров. Надо заметить, что это изначальное правило отнюдь не абсолютно. Действие закона аналогии увело многие из фамилий далеко от ударения в тех словах, с которыми они когда-то непосредственно были связаны. Ср.: Соколов, Сухарев. **Даже самая простая и самая распространенная русская фамилия  Иванов вызывает затруднения.** Дело в том, что в XIX веке в среде образованных людей было принято ударение  ИвАнов. Именно так произносится эта фамилия в драме Чехова, так же звучит фамилия писателя Всеволода Иванова.  **В произведении В. Саянова «Небо и земля» имеется такое разъяснение различной постановки ударения в этой фамилии: «Вот хотя бы армию взять: солдат – обязательно ИванОв, а офицер, хотя и десятый, а все-таки ИвАнов».**
            После революции на смену устаревающему ударению Иванов приходит **более демократическое – Иванов**, которое является общеупотребительным и сегодня.

Comment: Не стоит ничего предполагать. А уж ориентироваться на текст с фейковых сайтов - точно не стоит.

Comment: Вот с этого сайтика http://www.ufolog.ru/names/order/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2 http://www.ufolog.ru/names/order/%D0%9F%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2 http://www.ufolog.ru/names/order/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2 - ЯплакалЪ

Comment: Сайт, может быть, и фейковый, а может и нет, но вот насчет "не стоит" не могу с Вами согласиться. Я делаю предположение, что ударение в фамилии может зависеть от происхождения фамилии, и  не более того. Вы хотите доказать, что это однозначно не так? Или что Вы хотите?

Comment: *Я делаю предположение, что ударение в фамилии может зависеть от происхождения фамилии* - Да. Но это банальная вещь. Вот в отношении данной фамилии предположение о том, что происхождение как-то объясняет ударение на **последний** слог, - фантастично. Я согласен с Морковкиным. Более того, он дал весьма весомый аргумент **против** такого предположения. Вы же обернули против него мою фразу, которая совершенно не так звучала. И, кстати, ничего грубого по сути не несла.

Comment: Ну вообще-то я не говорил о фантастичности. Я хотел сказать только, что предположения подобного рода должны быть ограничены этимологией и абстрактными разговорами. Для практических целей они непригодны и вредны., поскольку идут вразрез с правилом, которое вы сформулировали. Ив**а**нов и Иван**о**в. Ну какое тут "происхождение"?

Comment: Это сообщение заслуживало минуса, удаленного модератором. Причина - в комментариях. Одной ссылки на совершенно фейковый сайт достааточно.

Answer (score 0):

"Мозгол**о**в" звучит как "ловец мозгов" - и это единственное, что заставляет думать, что такого ударения быть не может.

> Спросите у Мозголова. Фамилии произносятся так, как считает правильным носитель.

Согласен полностью.

Comment: Хороший аргумент. )))

Comment: А зачем заставлять себя думать, надо  спросить у Мозголова.

Comment: @Sibylla *А зачем заставлять себя думать, надо спросить у Мозголова* - Вас никто не заставляет.